# What is the best way to pass server side variables to JavaScript on the client side?

Tags: javascript

Our application uses a lot of configuration options. Those options need to be reflected on the client side in the form of User preferences, site wide preferences, etc.

Currently, we pass server side settings down to the client side in the form of JSON that is stored in custom attributes in the markup for a specific element (and no, our application currently doesn't worry about W3C validation). We then retrieve the data from the custom attribute, and parse it into a JSON object for use in script using jQuery.

One drawback to this is referencing attributes on elements from within event handlers. I know this is frowned upon, as it can create circular references, and subsequently memory leaks. I would much prefer to use jQuery's data function, but you can't invoke this from the server side at page render time.

What does everyone else do in this type of scenario?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Return the server data in JSON format. You could do this through AJAX by returning a JSON header, or simple page outup and `JSON.parse()`.

You can assign the JSON data directly to an element's data.

```
$('#elementid').data('serverdata', data);
```

### Update

After better understanding your situation I would suggest you use the `data-` attributes for three reasons.

1. You will have standards compliant markup.
2. The recent version of jQuery relies on these for the `.data` function.
3. The change will require little modification to your current application (changing the way custom attributes are output from `customAtt="value"` *to* `data-customAtt="value"`

[Here](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) is some more information on the data attributes.

Comment: +1, All answers are pretty good, but since he is using jQuery this would be the easiest solution

Comment: AJAX calls take time, and it's not so much about the actual time as perceived time. We're trying to minimize stuff popping up on the page after the initial load, as we feel this makes for a better user experience overall.

Comment: Then i would go with a string server variable parsed as json, and sent to the element's data.

Comment: Right, but this can get complicated as you need to know which element the data belongs to. The reason we use attributes currently is it relates the data to a particular element.

Comment: @steve_c - On second thought, just use the `data-` attributes. The latest version of jquery will look at these when using the `jQuery.data` function. This would essentially require you to change your custom attribute names fron `customAttribute` to `data-customAttribute`.

Comment: Josiah - that is actually a really great idea. I could make this change very simply and see how it works. If it works well, I'll let you know, and you can update your answer. I'll then mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can render in the page an inline script that defines a JS object with all the preferences. This way, your scripts have access to the data the moment the browser is done with the page load. The drawbacks:

- you have inline script in the page, which some people frown upon;
- caching the page might result in oder preferences being used for particular page instance;
- each page size is increased with the prefs size.

Or you can render in the page a link to an external script that declares the preferences. This way, the preferences don't block the page rendering, and can be cached separately by the browser. Drawbacks:

- the page might render with older preferences and then get update to the new preferences, which on slower networks might be visible;

Or you could directly add the data to an element using the HTML5 data attributes (thus being HTML5 conformant and jQuery.Data compatible, as it uses those as well). Drawback:

- you lose IE support;

Comment: This solution boils down to philosophy: do you frown upon inline scripts or not. We used to do this, but would rather not have inline scripts.

Answer (score 1):

At my projects I usually render such data as global JavaScript variables at the top of master page:

```
<script language="javascript">
var g_someOption=<%= Options.SomeOption.SerializeToJsonLiteral() %>;
var g_someOtherOption=<%= Options.SomeOtherOption.SerializeToJsonLiteral() %>;
// or
var g_globalOptions = {
    thirdOption:<%= Options.ThirdOption.SerializeToJsonLiteral() %>,
    foursOption:<%= Options.FourthOption.SerializeToJsonLiteral() %>
};
// or even via special helper that renders object above
<%= Html.RenderGlobalScriptVars() %>
</script>
```

If project is full of AJAX and user can stay on some page for a long time, it is possible to refresh settings periodically using AJAX requests to the server.

P.S. I've used aspx syntax, but I believe that you got an idea even if you're using some other language.

Comment: I'm not fond of globally defined variables inline. What you've done here is akin to attaching to the window object.

Comment: I posted an example that doesn't use global variables per say, only because it's wrapped in a function. But this is the simplest way to do it, globals aren't so bad if they are read-only, I would just put all these vars into a single object

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option, you can always do a

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="settings.php"></script>
```

to output stuff from PHP. You can use this to invoke the necessary data calls, for example. Just send the correct header.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use MVC, so I'm in the habit of making AJAX calls when the page loads to get objects I might need. I'm not sure what technology you're using, but it shouldn't be too hard to set up an endpoint that returns this JSON and call it when the DOM is ready. Then you can store it as a JavaScript variable and not worry about stuffing it into some element's attributes.

Comment: If you can, this is a good idea, however, many developers would rather not need an extra request since the json can be embedded in the html.

Comment: That's understandable, but in the JavaScript training I've had, using eval() and JSON.parse are evil :) So the only way to embed it without using these would be to embed some <script> tags which is also undesirable. There's no perfect answer.

Comment: JSON.parse isn't evil itself. Eval is only evil if you're executing code dynamically imo. What Juan said, that's what we're trying to avoid. We don't want multiple, or even one, AJAX request firing after initial page load as we don't want the perceived slowness from things 'popping' into the page.

Comment: @steve_c: you're right, JSON.parse isn't really evil, but to quote from 'JavaScript The Good Parts': "Currently, the best technique for obtaining data from a server in a web browser is through XMLHttpRequest."

Answer (score 0):

A good compromise is to render a single configuration object that is keyed by the ids you use for the nodes (or any other scheme that will let your handlers find the data). Instead of using inline handlers, set the handlers after the page is loaded. Then it should be easy to reference the json your server side created.

This example uses semi-globals

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // The following line would be generated in php using something like:
  // var cfg = <?= json_encode($cfg) ?>; 
  var cfg = {
     orders: [{total: 25, itemCount: 10}], 
     waiting: [{total: 20, reason: "Out of strock"}]
  };
  $('orders').click(function(){
    alert('You have a total of ' +  cfg.orders[0].itemCount + 'orders');
  });
})
</script>

<body>
<div id='orders'> Here are your orders</div>
</body>
```

Alternatively if you really want to scope your variables, you can do the following:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('orders').click(function(){
    var orders = <?= json_encode($orders) ?>; 
    alert('You have a total of ' +  orders[0].itemCount + 'orders');
  });
})
</script>

<body>
<div id='orders'> Here are your orders</div>
</body>
```

The above example is less flexible since you couldn't reuse the orders variable from other handlers if you needed to.

Comment: We don't use inline handlers at all. We reference configuration from custom attributes when needed. Sometimes this is via handlers, sometimes not. All handlers are attached by binding via jQuery. I'm nothing if not militant about good js practices.

Comment: Then you should be able to use the suggested approaches, mine and other people's. Not sure of what the intention of your comment is? You don't know how to provide the data to the handlers?

Comment: I'm looking for people to provide the best implementation of this functionality. I already have it working as is. I'm just not convinced it's the best way to do it.