# How to update user's page using express checkout

Tags: paypal

I would like to implement the in-context checkout that enables users to pay for a good and without having to reload another page (other than the paypal payment window) access the content. As I currently understand the process, the client will request my server for the paypal url to initiate the transaction. I will request paypal and send their `PAYMENTURL` as a response then if they complete the transaction they will be redirected to the url I provided paypal, but how can I then notify the client page that it is allowed to access the content without having them reload?

If you need a clearer example they have a mock website where there is a video playing, at some mark the video stops and then if you pay the video is then fully streamed, however the user did not have to reload the page for those changes to take place.

Comment: what you want to update?

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/digital-goods navigate to 'how it works'. After the user is done paying with paypal they never reload their game in order to update their status. I want to implement a similar feature and need to be notified after the user makes a successful payment.

Comment: i don't see "how it works" in https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/digital-goods

Comment: Right underneath the picture. It is an example of a racing game.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you don't want to reload the page ,so for example if you want to display the "Congratulations page" as shown in the [demo](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/digital-goods)
 you could either do :

- Do a ajax call , so once the payment is complete, the lightbox is closed and make a [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call to update the client page.
- Once lightbox is closed, display another pop up window to display the "Congratulations page" and prompt user to close it.

Comment: Yes but the problem is not on making the call, it is about obtaining the notification that the payment has been processed, or at least that the window was closed.

Comment: you will get a instant response `ack=success` in doexpresscheckout api call which means the payment is processed, whats your problem with that?

Comment: That is the notification my server receives and not the client.

Comment: you can pass server side variable to client side.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598223/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-server-side-variables-to-javascript-on-the-client-s

Comment: I haven't implemented DG, so IINM the OP's question (including myself I guess), is that after a user "approves", Paypal _will redirect_ to the set `return Url` (or `cancel Url`) where the rest of the EC flow continues (where OP will then invoke `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` to complete. That Paypal redirect, IINM, is the part that is confusing - it will "reload", assuming the redirect URL is the same url where the game _is being actively played_ (barring any game state/session that needs to be done). So clarity on that would be helpful - thnx!